# Rails / postgresQL ActiveRecord - HOW and WHY change the primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, primary-key, database-schema

I have a Rails project with postgresql database.

Let's say I have three models - Student, Teacher and Schedule - that joins a student and teacher

Student Model - Instead of going with the student_id as my primary key, I want to change that to the even_cooler_unique_student_number that a school has for a student.

Teacher Model - typical & traditional.

Schedule Model - I want to associate a Schedule (think - just a math class for now) with one teacher and its students. 
**How do I do that at the database level and with the AR associations?**

**What does changing the primary_key do to the database? To my associations through ActiveRecord?**

```
class CreateStudent < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.integer :unique_cooler_student_id, null: false
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateTeacher < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teachers do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :department

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateSchedules < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :schedules, id: false, force: true do |t|
      t.belongs_to :students, :primary_key => 'unique_cooler_student_id'
      t.belongs_to :teachers
      t.string :something_else


      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class Student
self.primary_key = 'unique_cooler_student_id'
  has_many :teachers, through: :classes
end

class Teacher
  has_many :students, through: :classes
end

class Schedule
  belongs_to :students
  belongs_to :teachers
end
```

Comment: Why would you not simply retain the primary key and add `even_cooler_unique_student_number` as a column in the students table? I'm sure you considered this ridiculously simple alternative, so there must be some reason you decided against it. An explanation would help us understand what you're trying to achieve and point the way to a suitable technical solution.

Comment: Have you read the rails guide on migrations? It's the best for answering this kind of stuff: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html Note I agree, you probably shouldn't change the primary key - just add a  new column. You can put constraints onto the column if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the name of primary key usually does very little besides adding a false sense of security - which is only by obscurity.

[You can however change the primary key from a auto-incrementing integer to a hash or some other sort of UUID.](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-start-using-uuid-in-activerecord-with-postgresql/) And there are many valid reasons to do so. This solely changes the method of generating primary keys.

You can even have separate external UUIDs which are used in url params for example. However this does not involve changing the primary key that ActiveRecord uses to join records:

```
Foo.joins(:bars).find_by(uuid: 'ABCD')
```

Of course ActiveRecord will let you crack out the [tin-foil hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_foil_hat) and use whatever primary keys you want - however you will need to specify the `primary_key` and probably also manually setup the foreign keys in your database to maintain referential integrity. So basically your losing every advantage of convention over configuration for no benefit.

You would have to do it like this:

```
class CreateSchedules < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :schedules, id: false, force: true do |t|
      t.references :students, foreign_key: false
      t.belongs_to :teachers
      t.string :something_else
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class AddStudensIdContraintToSchedules < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_foreign_key :schedules, :students, primary_key: "unique_cooler_student_id"
  end
end

class Schedule
  has_many :students, primary_key: 'unique_cooler_student_id'
end
```

This way AR uses `WHERE students.unique_cooler_student_id = 2` in the join query.

The only reason you would ever really want to do this this is if you have to use a legacy database and cannot change the database schema.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot specify the column of the foreign key when using `t.belongs_to` or `.references`, just true/false.